# How to analyze system freeze on x64 OS caused by Java application?

Tags: java, swing, crash, windows-7-x64

I have a java swing gui application (running for years on many different machines without problems) which causes system crashs on Windows 7 x64. I've tested the behaviour on several machines, and after an undefined time (between seconds and max. 2 minutes) the whole system will freeze - no way for any input (ctrl+alt+delete not working etc.).

As there are no exceptions, no Windows event logs and no noticeable increases in memory or cpu consumption, I wonder how to analyze the problem? Shouldn't the JVM prevent the whole system to freeze?

For testig purposes - can I determine that the application should be run with the x86 or x64 JRE/JDK? I've installed both on my machine and I've seen that the jar will always be executed with the x64 JRE - even if I explicitly choose 'open with' and the path to the x86 JRE.
Can this be controlled with JAVA_HOME variable or can I compile my program to be run in a specific version?

Comment: This sounds like the Java2D accelleration in Swing hitting a bug in the graphics driver, but I am unfamiliar with how to disable this in Java2D.

Comment: Following on from Thorbjørn's comment,it might be worth looking at http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html.

Comment: Pass -d32 for 32 bits, -d64 for 64-bits on the java commandline.

Comment: @Eelke:_tried -D32, but it still uses x64 JVM (also tried JAVA_HOME). still crashes

Comment: @Thorbjørn, Paul: tried all options, even noddraw=true and a brans new graphics driver - but still freeze!

Comment: First of all run the vendors hardware test to be 100% certain that all hardware is ok!

Comment: Have you tried to disable Direct3D (which has always been a problem for me on Vista 64 bits)? For this you need to set the `sun.java2d.d3d` property to `false` (ie pass `-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false` in the command-line).

Comment: @jfpoilpret: yes, i disabled it and also followed SUN's suggestions: "If problems persist, try setting the ddoffscreen property to false. If that doesn't solve the problems, try setting noddraw to true."

Comment: Since the bug seems due to the switch from 32 bits to 64 bits OS, you may have some thread synchronization issues when dealing with references. IIRC, changing a ref in 32 bits OS is atomic, whilst changing a ref in 64 bits is not.

Answer (score 0):

I could strip the problem down to RMI calls in combination with virus scanner/firewall software under Windows7 x64. After deinstalling the security software everything worked fine!